# Posting data to API is null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

When I post a json to the API the body received is always null. I'm using .net core 2.0

```
[HttpPost]
public  IActionResult UpdateProfile([FromBody] UserProfileView userProfile)
{
    return Ok();
}


public class UserProfileView
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public byte? YearOfBirth { get; set; }
    public List<UserAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Json I'm posting

```
{
    "id": "3e9f50c8-358a-4509-bbe4-4f4c6cc00676",
    "email": "joesamraj@outlook.com",
    "userName": "619795228409681",
    "displayName": "Joe Samraj",
    "firstName": "Joe Samraj",
    "lastName": "Muthuraj",
    "gender": "Male",
    "yearOfBirth": "1989",
    "attributes": []
}
```

Header: Content-Type:application/json

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a problem in datatype of your fields. You have yearofbirth field with data type bit and bit will accept values between 0 to 255 so you can change the type of yearofbirth to datetime .

for reference see this [byte datatype documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/byte)

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Solanki :). It worked. I changed that field from Age to Year of Birth which caused the issue.

Comment: welcome Joe Samraj , If this answer worked for you then you can vote up and make answer so other people who open your question will get idea of this answer worked or not.

Comment: Done :) . Thanks again :)